# Excel VBA: Import worksheets from workbooks into another workbook while performing operations

Tags: vba, excel

Goal: I want to import a worksheet from workbook1 to workbook3, but before that I want to make an addition to the importing sheet from workbook1. The addition is equal to one colum with calculations done from a third workbook - workbook2.

Set-up: I would want an button in workbook3 that prompt for file 1 - workbook1 and file 2 - workbook2, then it appends the calculation data from workbook 2 to a colum in workbook 1 before importing that entire sheet two workbook3 with the filename of the workbook or the worksheets name in workbook1.

Why?
It's a purchasing thing, I got a workbook - workbook1 with delivery accuracy percentage for a set of rows (suppliers). But I don't know just from workbook1 if this percentage is based on one PO-line (purchase orderline) or 100 (the latter which indicate more 'reliable' percentage). This data is found in workbook 2. Where each row is a PO-line and there is a colum indicating which supplier it is - SupplierID.

Is this even possible to peform calculation in some kind of 'temp'-mode? I was thinking to have an operation like two array lists with the same length, one would contain (create) the supplier ID and the other the corresponding nbr of PO-lines for that supplier. I would in my for-loop for the arrays in woorkbook2 just append +1 (PO-line) to array2 whenever the loop encountered a row with the same supplier again.

When the arrays would be done, I would just do a row-loop in workbook1 to writhe out the summarized nbr of PO-lines (one row for each supplier). When I would have this one sheet with all information. It would just be imported to workbook3 with the name of either workbook1 or the sheet in workbook1.

Is it possible and how? Or do you have any other suggestion based on what I want to achive given that the data is contained in two different workbooks, and that I need workbook3 where I compile this kind of data for each month (so there is already history in this file - workbook3). Of course I want minimal manual steps when trying to achive this.

Thanks!

Comment: To almost all questions asking "is this possible" the answer is typically "Yes".  However, as it stands this is not a good question for SO: to improve it you need to make it more specific.  Describe *exactly what is preventing you from doing what you want to do*.  Which part is giving you problems, what did you try, and what errors (etc) did you run into ?

Comment: Hi Tim! I haven't tried anything as of now, becuase I thought it wouldn't be possible to use commands in workbooks that weren't 'open', as I bealive you would seem to imply is possible, is it?

I'm a novich, but I know I can specify Sheets("xxx").Cells(... etc (perform operations in a sheet that isen't active), are you saying I could add to this; the particular file name before .Sheets("xxx")? If so, that I can read and writhe to non-active workbooks, how do use prompt for file's and store their names as Strings?

Comment: You can operate on workbook which are not active, but your options for workbooks which aren't open are much more limited.  You didn't mention in your question that you wanted to work with closed workbooks.

Comment: Sry, I guess in my mind those files (workbooks) weren’t open, except the one that will prompt for those files (workbook 3). And by ‘temp’ I somewhat meant performing operations and calculations in not open (active) workbooks. Again, sorry for the confusion.. However based this ‘new’ information, is it still possible to do the kind of operations that I described (that are possible in open – active workbooks) in not active workbooks? Or do you have any other suggestions and how I could achieve what I’m trying to do? In my world a workbooks is a file, a sheet a sheet within a workbook – correct?

Comment: All you can do with a closed workbook is read values (and maybe if you use ADO you could write to one) but you cannot perform a calculation in a closed workbook.  Is it important that these workbooks remain closed, or could you open them to do what you want?

Comment: I understand. It's not very important, but of course not doing so would entail an additional work activity. The main reason I stated it was because I didn't want to create a new macro for each new file (i.e. workbook 1/2), just one (or more) but only in workbook 3 - which is the file that will be kept up-to date. After the data have been 'read' from w-b's 1/2 these will be just 'scrap'. But I think I still need to promt since w-b's 1/2 have the current month name in their file name's. But just having them open, and still prompt is okey it this would permit the calculations I want.

Comment: Once you've prompted the user for the input workbooks it's no additional work for them (and likely insignificant work for your macro) to open those file via VBA and perform the work you want. Once you're done you can then close them. If you turn off screen updating while doing this the end-user won't even know the files were opened.  I'm not sure I follow your concerns about needing to create additional macros for the other files: your VBA can all be in a single workbook and can operate on any open Excel file...

Comment: This sounds terrific! I guess I imposed a set of limitations in my first post based on my perception of what the VBA could do and how, but I think I understand now. Then it's just the mather of writing this code. Can you link to a post describing prompt and that of  open xlsx-files. And how I perform operations in an other workbook than active, but still opened (by the macro). Is it as a implied before Workbook(" ' String' ").Sheets(" 'String '")... as usual.? And again how do the VBA read workbook filename and sheet names from w-b's 1/2 into a Strings in w-b 3 that i can use in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim v1, v2

    Set wb1 = PromptForWorkbook("Select first input file")
    If wb1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set wb2 = PromptForWorkbook("Select second input file")
    If wb2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    v1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Value
    v2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value

    'etc etc

    wb1.Close False 'don't save changes
    wb2.Close False 'don't save changes

End Sub

Function PromptForWorkbook(sMsg As String) As Workbook
    Dim f, wb As Workbook
    f = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
                                    Title:=sMsg, MultiSelect:=False)
    If f <> False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    End If
    Set PromptForWorkbook = wb
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I can report that I now have the script in order that does what I want. :) It opens the books but as you suggested without any messages.